# Interactive Install of a deb file using software installer(snap-store) is not asking for the debconf options and uses default values in 20.04 & 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, debconf

I am trying to install a software with deb file using software installer(snap-store) from the GUI and it has some options to be selected during installing which uses debconf. While installing using the default software installer(snap-store), I am not asked for any options, the installation is going through by taking default value of those options. Observed this so far in Ubuntu 20.04 & 22.04. Also snap-store seems to be the new default software centre that comes by default with Ubuntu.
If I install the same deb using gnome-software (Installed gnome-software manually didnt come with Ubuntu) or command line everything works fine and I am asked to select options.

Any pointers on this would help.
Does debconf options work with snap store ? Is there a config that I need to turn on in snap-store to make this work ?